# How to set up a file of constants in a Framework in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, constants

I created a Framework to share some code between my iOS app and my WatchKit extension, but I don't know how to create a single file for just constants.

Basically I want a file containing all the constants for my project to be available to both my iOS and WatchKit app, therefore I'm putting it in the Framework. But how do I create such a file in Objective-C?

What should I choose under `subclass`? Do I need both a `.h` and `.m` file? Should I include an `interface` and `implementation`? I don't want to create a class or object, I simply want a file of `NSString` constants. What would that look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to just create a constants.h file that you include where you need it or include it in your `XX-Prefix.h` file and it will automatically be imported into all your files.

Then just have `#define YOUR_STRINGS @"your strings"` in the `constants.h` file and then you can use them freely.

If it's part of a framework you might want to prefix all your constants' names to avoid a name collision.

Comment: Thanks! Should I include `Foundation.h` or anything like that in my `.h` file?

Comment: I also heard it's better to use `const` as opposed to `#define`. What's your thought on this?

Comment: dont need to include anything in the constants.h (except maybe other constant files for convenience), using a const string could be better, the define is just a preprocessor command, so the strings are inserted into your code as hardcoded strings at compile time, while a const string would be an actual variable, slightly different in the implementation, but to you they will be effectively the same, so just pick one and stick with it really. but ye I dont really know the advantage of using the one over the other